# Flow: What's the correct way to specify an interface for a subclass?

Tags: flowtype

A question about Flow interfaces and Javascript clases...

Assume I have the following interface:

```
declare interface IA {
    x(): string;
}
```

and the following base class, which has one method, and which implements IA:

```
class A implements IA {
    x(): string
}
```

Assume I want to create a subclass of A, called B, which adds a method:

```
class B extends A {
    y(): number
}
```

...how do I specify an interface for B (call it IB)? And how do I indicate that B implements IB, while still implementing IA through it inheritance of class A?

Would IB have to repeat **all** the methods found in IA?

Would B need to indicate that it implements **both** IA and IB, like the following...

```
class B extends A implements IA, IB {
    y(): number
}
```

?

The documentation doesn't seem to cover how to do interfaces where subclassing is involved.

Thank you.

-Allan

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two main options. Option 1 would be good if you truly want `B` to be a subclass of `A`, whereas option 2 works well if you want to separate class `A` and class `B`.

#### Option 1

You can write an interface `IB` that extends the interface `IA`

```
declare interface IB extends IA {
    y(): number;
}
```

and have `class B implements IB`. Note that `B` will need to implement both `x` and `y`. See [here](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCCSAgvAN4BQ8F8AHgBQCUAXPAM6owoDmA3KQL6mlIUZs3hFEAWwAOEEBJBpRhEuUq1GLNpxWVKcVAFcYyeAHJTPXf36lQQuEjQZsueHgBC8EFXTJgSojJdAE96JmQDCQAjDB4bIRF4T0kZOQVUJU8gtTDNdmQOHV14fSMTc0tKGxDciOiMIt1S43gABkqKawEE0QA5AHtUZOlZeUU3LNUKUI06mJhGvRBDFvap+C7BaESCCGZ+gaGkEbTxj0X1JlZ8wuym5bKzC3XrIA) for an example.

#### Option 2

You can write an interface `IB` that does not extend `IA`

```
declare interface IB {
    y(): number;
}
```

and have `class AB implements IA, IB`. See [here](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEBLAdgFxDAZlMCCSAgvAN4BQ8F8AHgBQCUAXPAM6owoDmA3KQL6mlQkWAhTosOfACES5eAE96TZAFcAtgCMMPfqWHNm8AjMRqADhBBqQaQ4QA08PDLKVqSlm06y3FOKhUYZHgAchCeN103RUZ4VU0MH19-QOCABgjKfl19QwA5AHtUYyRzS2tbJwJHZySKGOV1LRg6yhSg+Ay5CmyBXKMIZgLC4pMyqxtUO2qnF273WNZ2ZA5WvxAAjrDMnr4gA) for an example of how that would work.